# Getting values of CloudFormation instrinsic functions within a jinja template

Tags: amazon-web-services, jinja2, aws-cloudformation

I use a combination of jinja and CloudFormation YAML templates to define my infrastructure stack. I'm attempting to create CloudWatch alarms for DynamoDB global tables. The metric name being ReplicationLatency. I was looking at this wiki for reference to begin with - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/globaltables_monitoring.html

Now, after looking at the metrics in the CloudWatch console, I realized that the ReceivingRegion is always all other regions, except the source region itself. i.e. for example, if you open the CW console in us-east-2 (Ohio), the ReplicationLatency metrics appear for every other region apart from us-east-2. I validated this assumption by looking at the same metric in multiple regions.

Now, in order to create alarm for the DDB table in us-east-2, I'd require the list of all other regions where the global table exists. I'm trying to understand how I'd be able to get that part within the CF template/jinja template.

I was initially thinking that I'd have a jinja macro similar to this:

```
{% macro cw_alarms(current_region) %}
  {% set global_table_all_regions = ['us-east-1', 'us-east-2', 'us-west-1', 'us-west-2', 'eu-west-1', 'eu-west-2', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-northeast-1', 'ap-northeast-2', 'ap-southeast-1', 'ap-southeast-2']

  {% set alarm_region_suffix_list = ddb_global_table_regions | reject(current_region %}
  {% for alarm_region_suffix in alarm_region_suffix_list %}
SomeAlarmName:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    Namespace: "AWS/DynamoDB"
    MetricName: "ReplicationLatency"
    Dimensions:
    - Name: TableName
      Value: Ref TableName
    - Name: Receiving-Region
      Value: alarm_region
    Statistic: p90
    Period: '300'
    EvaluationPeriods: '1'
    Threshold: 5000
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
   {% endmacro %}
```

But the problem arises here that there's noway for me to invoke this macro with the current_region variable set properly. For example, I don't think there's anyway to do something like:

```
set my_variable_region = Ref 'AWS::Region'
```

I'm trying to understand if there's any other alternative to do this? Has anybody come across this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a condition for every region that's only false if it's the current region. The region name could be in the condition name. You can then use each of those conditions in the appropriate resource. This way the resource for the current region will be defined but disabled because of the condition.

Something like:

```
Conditions:
{% for region in global_table_all_regions %}
  IsNot{{ region }}: !Not [!Equals [ !Ref AWS::Region, {{ region }} ]]
{% endfor %}
Resources:
{% for region in global_table_all_regions %}
  Alaram{{ region }}:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Condition: IsNot{{ region }}
    Properties:
      Namespace: "AWS/DynamoDB"
      MetricName: "ReplicationLatency"
      # ... insert props here
{% endfor %}
```